# How to solve loading issue of the Select.Async component from react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using the Select.Async component from react-select along with redux-form. I pass a load options function to the Select.Async and that function makes a request only once. The first time it is called, it makes a get request with axios and returns all the options. The problem I've got is that the first time it loads the options (fetches them), it first shows it is Loading as it is in the picture, but then it erases what the user input and shows no options. The second time a user types it works because no request is made but the options are taken from the state.

Thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: are you sure the value passed to Async is handled correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using a stateless component instead of a class.